# Is it possible to have an if statement in Java that doesn't make use of relational operators?

Tags: java, if-statement, operators, relational

This isn't for a specific code, I'm just curious. Relational operators as in `==`, `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=`.

Comment: Yes, `if(true)` or any other boolean condition

Comment: Of course: `if (x.isSomeMethodTrue())`...

Answer (score 2):

Of course:

```
if (processing)
{
    // enter if the boolean processing is true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a function that returns a boolean value

```
  public boolean isTrue()
  {
    //Some code
    //return true or false

  }
```

Then the 'if' statement will look something like this:

```
  if(isTrue())
     //Do something
  else
    //Do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually,, the if statement only know wether if it is a true or false value.
But in case of integer, it returnx true if what inside bracket is correct.
Like:

```
int n=10;  
if(n==10){}
```

The value inside bracket will return true since it is correct. Return false if you change the bracket into `n>10`

Different condition goes for String..

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
if (x) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
if (!x) {
    ...
}
```

where `x` is a boolean or anything that returns a boolean.

Heck, go crazy:

```
boolean x = false, y = false;

if (x = y = x = !y) {

}
```

(notice that we're using `=` not `==` here - you would probably *very* rarely want to do something like this, if ever.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Generally speaking, the syntax of an `if` statement is `if (cond) { xxx(); }` where `cond` is **any expression which evaluate to a `boolean`**.

Which means the following are all valid:

```
if (true)           // Literal value true
if (m.find())       // m is a Matcher; .find() returns true if match
if (3 <= 3)         // operator
if (a && b)         // a and b are expressions evaluating to a boolean;
                    // && is the logical "and" operator
```

And so on.